# Flutter geolocator plugin Geolocator().getCurrentPosition doesnt return accurate lng and lat coordinate

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter, dart, geolocation

I just started on flutter and i not sure why when i cant get the accurate coord using geolocator plugin on iOS simulator.

It returns this, is it 1 decimal point and gives an inaccurate location

> Lat: 1.3, Long: 103.8

How can I make it return this?

> 1.3825983,103.8814173

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home(this.listType);
  final String listType;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  // final LatLng _center = const LatLng(1.290270, 103.851959);
  Position _pos;
  Widget _mapWidget; 

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _mapWidget = SpinKitRotatingCircle(
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 50.0,
    );
    getCurrentLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    GeolocationStatus geolocationStatus  = await Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();
    print(geolocationStatus);

    Position currPos = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    print(currPos);

    setState(() {
      _pos = currPos;
      _mapWidget = initMapWidget();
    });
  }

  Widget initMapWidget () {
    return GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(_pos.latitude, _pos.longitude),
        zoom: 15.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _mapWidget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by parsing `lat` and `long` to `double`.

`target: LatLng(_pos.latitude.toDouble(), _pos.longitude.toDouble()),`

Comment: still the same, doesnt return double.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the location accuracy as high

```
Position currPos = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
print(currPos);
```